# saving api data into a json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have some python files, which consist of functions. I have another python file let it be sample.py, where I will be calling those functions, so whenever I am calling the functions, the information from the function should be saved into an external JSON file.
Example:

```
    def Addtext(Text, TextColor=(0,0,0), TextLevel=5):
        pass
```

This is the function which I will be calling in my sample.py.
so whenever the function is called, the information inside the function, that can be anything, such as Text Text-color, text level, should be taken and saved into a JSON file.
so whenever the function is hit the information should be saved into a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the usage of a decorator? It would add the "save" functionality for each function that is going to be called and needed to save to json.

An e.g.:

```
import json

def saving_to_json(func):
    def wrapper():
        data_to_save = func()
        with open('saved_data.json', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(data_to_save, outfile)
            outfile.write('\n')
    return wrapper

@saving_to_json
def add_text():
    data = {"Test 123": "Hello"}
    print(data)
    return data

add_text()
```

Not the focus of the answer, but as an advice, in python "usually" variables and function names are snake cased.